# 8-letter word that uses all letter keys on a telephone

Tags: word

I have found a few 11-letter words that use every key except 0 or 1 on a standard telephone (like EXPLORATION), but I haven't found any shorter such words. What is the shortest word we can make that uses all letter keys on a telephone?

As for hitting all but one key, EXPLOIT does the job with the minimum possible 7 letters.

Comment: Some phones put the Q and Z together on the 0 rather than having 4 letters on two of the keys.  Might be worth a follow-up question looking for a 9-letter word with that key arrangement.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The shortest possible is obviously 8 letters, using each of the number keys 2-9 exactly once. The online word search tool [Qat](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=%2F%5Babc%5D%5Bdef%5D%5Bghi%5D%5Bjkl%5D%5Bmno%5D%5Bpqrs%5D%5Btuv%5D%5Bwxyz%5D&ent=Search&dict=4) finds 3 such words:

ENTHALPY, UNEASILY, UNFAIRLY

Picking a different dictionary gives even more results, although many of them are either two-word phrases (e.g. BOX KITES, WILD OATS) or words I have never seen before (e.g. BLINTZES, EPICOTYL).

Comment: You've never eaten [blintzes](https://tastesbetterfromscratch.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Blintzes-Web-12.jpg)?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I don't think so. Never even heard of them before today.

Comment: Go find yourself a place that sells them (or find a recipe)

Comment: Across all the dictionaries offered by Qat, I found 151 words. My favorite is "playtime". [Complete list here](https://pastebin.com/54CSsDTT).

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger Came for entertainment, left with extra weight

Answer (score 23):

**keypunch**

I used https://chat.openai.com/ and used this prompt: "8 letter English word that uses all letter keys on a telephone?". It gave me the answer "keypunch".

Comment: This works, although using ChatGPT is bad.

Comment: @mathlander Yeah, sorry. I was just excited that it even worked.

Comment: +1 for honesty and full disclosure.

Comment: @NoahGav this is fine. It's using ChatGPT as a tool, and not trying to ask ChatGPT to write the answer for you. You just used it to find a word, then you report the word here. That's perfectly fine. What's not allowed is to simply copy paste ChatGPT output into here.

Comment: It's on theme as well!

Comment: It must have been a fluke of luck, because I asked the exact same question, and it repeated a letter. I pointed it out, it apologized and acknowledged that it really repeated it, and came up with another word instead... with the same mistake.

Answer (score 6):

I've found some more words in the [corncob wordlist](http://www.mieliestronk.com/wordlist.html):

- **unfairly**
- **knitwear**
- **playtime**
- **uneasily**
- **dilatory** - slow to act.
- **enthalpy** - a thermodynamic quantity equivalent to the total heat content of a system. It is equal to the internal energy of the system plus the product of pressure and volume.
- **adroitly** - in a clever or skilful way.
- **idolatry** - the worship of idols.
- **gunwales** - the upper edge or planking of the side of a boat or ship. (not sure if plurals count)

Comment: Notably, three of these are anagrams of each other!

Comment: Dilatory, adroitly, idolatry

Answer (score 3):

I found 10 more words that are interesting and a bit more common:

- **waterlog**
- **exitplan**
- **tensibly**
- **blowiest**
- **unflashy**
- **fistblow**
- **gunlayer**
- **planview**
- **rockview**
- **royalite**

Comment: What was your source for these? Five of these are two-word sequences.

Comment: Interesting. Useful to note which dictionary(/ies)/wordlist(s) you used, and which authoritative source says that 'exit plan', 'fist blow', 'plan view', 'rock view' are a single word; the OP asked for single words.

Answer (score 3):

I ran grep on a large dictionary, I don't remember where I downloaded it from.

```
grep '^........$' words_alpha | grep '[abc]' | grep '[def]' | grep '[ghi]' | grep '[jkl]' | grep '[mno]' | grep '[pqrs]' | grep '[tuv]' | grep '[wxyz]'
```

Not being a native english speaker I have trouble validating the results.
I found the words below that are accepted by Chrome's spellcheck:

> adroitly blintzes blowiest cryolite dilatory enthalpy epicotyl
> foxtails gunwales haylofts idolatry interlay keypunch knitwear
> legatory ovalwise playtime sodality steamily tankwise triazole
> uneasily unfairly valorize waterlog wrentail

And these that are not (maybe neologisms, slang or non-US spellings):

> anesthyl bungerly clientry dicotyls dovyalis filatory galewort
> geolatry gunlayer hectorly jarovize kyanites lauwines lipocyte
> lyterian lopheavy neuralgy ozarkite penality pentylic plowgate
> scolytid taleysim tensibly twangler twangles twankies unbirdly
> unclergy unflashy unsagely whetrock

Comment: I can't help but think that anyone who uses the work "neologism" correctly is a native english speaker.

Comment: The similarities in vocabulary between languages is higher among the complicated words than among the simple ones.  Neologism In French it is "néologisme".